# Try to revisit the URL in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, polling

I want to visit certain REST URI.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url + "result/" + ticket_id,
    success: function(data) {
        setTimeout(function(){pollResponse(url,data.id);}, 3000);
    }
});
```

This works. It visits the URI, and the views function does its job. So on `success` it moves on to the new URI.

```
function pollResponse(url, id)
{
    $.getJSON(url + "status/" + id, {},
        function(data) {
            if (data.report == null)
            {
                console.log(data.status_response);
                setTimeout(function(){pollResponse(url, id);}, 3000);
            }
            else
                console.alert('DONE!');
        }
    );
};
```

If the URI does not return `report` as part of the data (or being empty), then we will ask again in 3 seconds.

But after it prints the log in the console, the response stops with `[200] OK`.
It doesn't ask the server any more.

All I did with my Python's views function is

```
from cornice import Service
status = Service(name='status',
                    path=root+'/status/{some_id}',
                    description=status_desc)
@status.get()
def get_status(request):
   // do something

   if (...):
      return {'report': ''}
   else:
      return {'report': 'NOT EMPTY')
```

Comment: `url` and `id` look specific to the request, not within the scope, ie, closure of the `setTimeout` callback itself.

Comment: Should `if (data.report == null)` be `if (data.report !== null)`?

Comment: @JaredFarrish I don't think it really has the scope problem after numerous testing... but thanks.

Comment: @ChrisClower Thank you Chris. Part of the problems was the comparison failed. `""` is not null in Javascript. Thanks. I upvote your comment. The comparison should have been just `if (data.report == "")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have a parsing issue in the result or a cross domain issue. Try changing your code to use the `ajax` function directly:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url + "status/" + id,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {},
    success: function(data) {
        if (data.report == null)
        {
            console.log(data.status_response);
            setTimeout(function(){pollResponse(url, id);}, 3000);
        }
        else
            console.alert('DONE!');
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.error(textStatus);
        console.error(errorThrown);
        console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
    }
);
```

This way you can see if the response is causing an error. If there is a parsing error, you can get the data through jqXHR.responseText on the error function and see what is wrong.

The shortcut functions for AJAX in jQuery error silently on many cases. This is why i rarely use them.

Comment: Thank you. It improves the problem, although the error didn't catch. It was actually a logical error.  `""` is not null. Thanks

Comment: I've spotted that at first sight, but you said you was getting a 200 OK, so i though that it was being printed by the first line on that check. I sure don't have payed attention enough. Glad you catched it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `setTimeout` in the polling function should be:

```
setTimeout(function(){pollResponse(url, data.id);}, 3000);
```

Instead of:

```
setTimeout(function(){pollResponse(url, id);}, 3000);
```

Comment: I know the JS code is horrible lol. But the id will reuse the same id from before. Is this another scoping problem!?

Comment: @User007 Ah, I see, you've passed it in there from the first AJAX call.